# "[HandleError]" at class level, override at method level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

I have a C# MVC 3 controller with the HandleError attribute at the class level

```
[HandleError(View = "MyErrorPage")]   
public class MyController : Controller
{
```

At the method level I've got:

```
[HttpPost]
[MyExceptionHandler]
public ActionResult DoSomeStuff(FormCollection fc)
{
```

where MyExceptionHandler looks like:

```
public class MyExceptionHandlerAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //do Stuff

        JsonResult result = new JsonResult {
            Data = new { 
                    error = "Your request blah blah...."
                }
            };
        filterContext.Result = result;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine on my localhost. I.e. upon an exception in method 'DoSomeStuff' [MyExceptionHandler] is invoked, the class level [HandleError] is not.
However, on a dev environment, the class level [HandleError] comes into play. The result is that the HandleError view=MyErrorPage is rendered.

1. I'm aware that [HandleError] is redundant on localhost but open to correction (or configuration options)?
2. I'm unsure if on the development environment (not localhost) MyExceptionHandler is invoked at all. It may be invoked before the class level [HandleError]?

My problem is that I need [MyExceptionHandler] to be the only handler invoked.
I'd like to be able to have [HandleError] invoked on my localhost so I can simulate the issue locally.

Comment: Could the `//do Stuff` stuff that you haven't shown throw an exception? If it can it would explain the behavior. Also which HTTP verb are you using in your AJAX request when invoking the `DoSomeStuff` action - GET or POST? If you are using GET that would also explain your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response Darin. No, I don't think the //do stuff can throw an exception. POST is the HTTP verb being used. I've update the code inthe question to show this. The form specifies method="POST". Thanks.

Comment: You don't think or you have verified and are sure?

Comment: Good point, I'm 99.9% sure there wouldn't be an exception but having trouble verifying at the moment due to IT problems. I'll comment here when I verify. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

```
[HandleError(View = "MyErrorPage", Order = 2)]
```

solved the problem (Specifically, `Order = 2`).

The reason is that this handler now has a lower priority than the method level handler. Thus, the method level handler is executed first, as per the code above , it flags the exception as handled therefore the Controller level handler is never executed.

The reason the problem is only on localhost is because [HandleError] is not enabled on localhost by default. However, on the development environment it was automatically enabled.

I would then think that I'd be able to see the problem on localhost by setting:

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On" />
```

but for some reason, that didn't work.... anyway,separate issue I guess.

FYI, I've attempted to summarise all this error handling stuff (with a focus on AJAX) here: http://outbottle.com/net-mvc-3-custom-ajax-error-handling-2/

Thanks